# how to show argparse subcommands in groups?

Tags: python, argparse

For a program with many subcommands, I'd like to show them logically grouped in the --help output.  Python argparse has a [`add_argument_group`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument_group) method, but it doesn't seem compatible with subparsers.  subparsers can only be added to the top level `ArgumentParser`, and `_SubParsersAction` doesn't allow argument groups.  Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do it in any straightforward way, other than implementing a custom `HelpFormatter`.

You can find some more information on `HelpFormatter` flavors in [this part of the documentation.](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#formatter-class)