# How to show help for all subparsers in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have made a Python script that is doing a lot of actions, so it has many options, so I divided it to subparsers that also use parent parsers for common options grouping.

I want a help option that will show the help for all commands with their options, is it possible without overriding the format_help method?

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020898/how-to-show-argparse-subcommands-in-groups), but the grouping is not critical for me, I just want the options there.

For example:

```
general_group = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,add_help=False)
general_group.add_argument('--threads', action='store_true', default=False)
second_group = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,add_help=False)
second_group.add_argument('--sleep', action='store', default=60, type=int)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
subparsers=parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.add_parser('Restart',parents=[general_group,second_group])
subparsers.add_parser('Start',parents=[general_group])

args = parser.parse_args()
```

In this case I would like that if someone runs ./script.py -h they'll see the threads option in the help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are passing `parents` paramenter to the subparsers? Using `general_group` as "parent"(meaning `subparsers = general_group.add_subparsers()`) and *not* passing `parents=[...]` actually *shows* the `--threads` option when doing `./script.py -h`.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 such groups...

Comment: Then what you posted was not a minimal working example. Post some code that shows exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Made the example more similar to my actual code, I can't post the exact code here because it's internal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that in the lines:

```
subparsers=parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.add_parser('Restart',parents=[general_group,second_group])
subparsers.add_parser('Start',parents=[general_group])
```

You are adding `general_group` as parent to the subparsers, so the main parser does not know about them, which results in `./script.py -h` to not show `--threads`. If you plan to put it as parent of all the subparsers then you should put it as top parser parent:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[general_group])
subparsers=parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.add_parser('Restart',parents=[second_group])
subparsers.add_parser('Start')
```

Which results in:

```
$ python script.py -h
usage: script.py [-h] [--threads] {Restart,Start} ...

positional arguments:
  {Restart,Start}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --threads
```

Note however that in this case the option is part only of the parent parser and not the subparsers, which means that the following:

```
$python script.py --threads Start
```

is correct, while:

```
$ python script.py Start --threads
usage: script.py [-h] [--threads] {Restart,Start} ...
script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --threads
```

Because `--threads` is not "inherited" by the subparser. If you want to have `--threads` also in the subparser you must specify it in its `parents` argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[general_group])
subparsers=parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.add_parser('Restart',parents=[general_group, second_group])
subparsers.add_parser('Start', parents=[general_group])
```

This should do what you want:

```
$ python script.py -h
usage: script.py [-h] [--threads] {Restart,Start} ...

positional arguments:
  {Restart,Start}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --threads
$ python script.py Start -h
usage: script.py Start [-h] [--threads]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --threads
```

Comment: Sounds like it answers my question, I'll test it and if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted, meanwhile voted up.