# Python, argparse: different parameters with different number of arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to write a Python script called `sync` that has three or four modes of operation, each receiving a different number of arguments. For example,

```
sync set_version <build> <version_number>
sync get_version <build>
sync has_started <build_1> <build_2> ... <build_n>
```

I've tried using `argparse`'s subparsers for each mode of operation:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Build synchronization mechanism')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_get_version = subparsers.add_parser('get_version')
parser_get_version.add_argument('build')

parser_update_version = subparsers.add_parser('update_version')
parser_update_version.add_argument('build')
parser_update_version.add_argument('version')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

The problem is that the help message is not reflecting the structure of the arguments of each operation modes. Instead, it simply lists the operation modes:

```
usage: sync.py [-h] {get_version,update_version} ...

Build synchronization mechanism

positional arguments:
  {get_version,update_version}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

**How do I force argparse to display a full help message, with all the subparsers parameters?**

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918804/how-to-show-help-for-all-subpasers-in-argparse

Comment: You might want to check out [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/) for this job - I hear good things about the library. You give a description in a similar style to the help you normally get, and it automatically parses the command line args into a simple data structure, and it appears to output the help as you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Each sub-command has it's own help; try `sync.py get_version --help`, for example.

You'd have to override the help action yourself, and loop over the subcommands and print help for each. This requires some foibling with internal attributes:

```
class HelpAction(argparse._HelpAction):
     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
         parser.print_help()

         for group in parser._subparsers._group_actions:
             group.choices.values()[0].print_help()

         parser.exit()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Build synchronization mechanism',
                                 add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action=HelpAction, default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
    help=argparse._('show this help message and exit'))
```

You probably want to tweak the output some more though.

Comment: That's true, but I'd like to list the help for all the modes of operation together.