# How do I display all optional arguments of argparse for all subparsers?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to modify the `-h` in order to display optional parameters even when the subparser is not specified.

It seems that by default -h displays information only for the main parser and in order to display the ones specific for each subparser I need to call `script.py xxx -h` where xxx is the subparser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [argparse subparser monolithic help output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094215/argparse-subparser-monolithic-help-output)

Comment: There isn't a builtin mechanism.  The main parser displays what it knows, the subparsers what they know.  So you have to collect the information yourself.  Do you want to do it in a superficial way, or are you willing to get into the guts of `argparse`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581439/subparser-show-help-for-both-parser-and-subparser is a similar recent question.

Comment: If previous answers are inadequate, you need to give an example with desired output.  There are too many ways of displaying this information to give simple general solution.