# Nested argparse parsers and help message

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

### The situation

One module (let's call it `A`) implements a "primary" argparse parser, that parses known arguments common for all children classes (using `parser.parse_known_args(argv)`). Then, it passes remaining arguments to another object that it's calling. Let's assume it may be either object of class `B` or `C`. Both `B` and `C` have their own argparse parsers which parse remaining arguments (using `parser.parse_args(argv)`). They take different arguments, specific to class `B` or `C`.

Example snippet from class `A`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Parent parser",
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    allow_abbrev=False
)
parser.add_argument('--argument_A', action="append", default=None,
                          help="Help of first argument of parser A")
known, remaining_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
my_obj = self.create_obj(b_or_c, remaining_args)
```

Example snippet from class `B`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Class B parser",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
        allow_abbrev=False
    )
    parser.add_argument('--argument_B', action="append", default=None,
                              help="Help of first argument of parser B")
    B_arguments_parsed = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

Example snippet from class `C`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Class C parser",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
        allow_abbrev=False
    )
    parser.add_argument('--argument_C', action="append", default=None,
                              help="Help of first argument of parser C")
    C_arguments_parsed = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

While implementing passing the arguments and parsing them in the right places was easy, I didn't find a simple solution to print proper help.

### The question

How do I implement help message so that my parent parser (from class `A`) prints it's own help and help from parser `B` or `C`?

I would like to see help message from parser `A` and, depending on which object was selected, parser `B` or `C`.

Comment: Did you have a look at [sub parsers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, I should have mentioned it. For now, there was a design decision to keep the parsers separated because of other project dependencies. This way I can't use sub_parser AFAIK. Maybe, if there is no better way, I will need to refactor to support sub_parsers.

Comment: The subparser mechanism doesn't display a unified help either.

Comment: You can get a formatted string with `parser.format_help()`, `parserB.format_help()`, etc.  But it's up to you to join them.  And look at `parser.print_help` and the Help Action subclass for ideas on how to invoke a customized help.

Comment: Similar issue for subparsers: [Subparser — show help for both parser and subparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581439/subparser-show-help-for-both-parser-and-subparser)

Comment: Thanks! I think I will manually join helps with `parsers.format_help()`.